# Enable DD4T Logging - Page Not Found

Tags: dd4t

I'm getting a "Page Not Found" error from DD4T, but I'm not sure why.

How do I enable logging for DD4T?  I'm getting the other CD log messages, but I don't see anything for DD4T.

Comment: Java or dotNet?

Comment: http://blog.trivident.com/2012/08/logging-in-dd4t/

Comment: .net              _______________________

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming .NET (may apply to Java too).

The route that is configured out of the box catches everything, because of this "Page Not Found" could be caused by the following things:

1. Missing images
2. Favicon not present
3. You're typing the wrong URL (without index.html or similar)

You can use the `IgnoreRoute` method in your routing config to ignore requests for a particular file or extension but you may want to check the Request.Url property for what is being requested and figure out why it is missing.

To actually answer the question for .NET you can configure the `DD4T.LoggerClass` Web.config setting with the class to use for logging. I tend to use log4net - you'll need to add a reference to log4net and then add the web.config setting like so:

`<add key="DD4T.LoggerClass" value="DD4T.LogWrappers.Log4Net.Log4NetLogger, DD4T.LogWrappers.Log4Net" />`

A word of warning: DD4T logs *a lot* of things and this can impact performance so remember to set your log level appropriately.

More here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx

Comment: I added the config entry you listed, added the log4net-specific entries, but I don't get any log messages

Comment: Have you called XmlConfigurator.Configure somewhere in your application to initialise log4net? Can you log normally?

Comment: UPDATE: The DD4T log4net config entries can be found here: https://github.com/ThijsBorst/DD4T.Package.Sample/blob/master/DD4T.Package.Sample/Web.config