# DD4T logging issue | files always having 0 KB size

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, dd4t, dd4t-2, logging

I am trying to setup Logging for DD4T but it doesn't works despite many similar issues/question found.

I was following the fixes mentioned in this question: [Enable DD4T Logging - Page Not Found](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2776/enable-dd4t-logging-page-not-found), still i am unable to see anything written in log files. Log Files get created but always have 0 KB size.

Below is Configuration:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="App_Data/dd4t.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

I am able to browse the home page of my website, so expecting DD4T to write something to logs.

Please suggest what next to check and fix.

Comment: Try to call XmlConfigurator.Configure() in global.asax.cs?

Comment: Yes, I have called it in Application_start() of Global.asax.cs file

Comment: Do you have this <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" /> configSections, which version of log4net.dll used.

Try to enable debug and access the page
  <log4net debug="true">
    <root>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
      <level value="DEBUG" />
    </root>
  </log4net>

To make sure application app pool has write permission to log folder

Comment: Yes, I have the "log4net" section in web.config, also I have tried that 'Debug' thing as well. 

Can you please confirm which version of DD4T.LogWrappers.Log4Net.dll , I should use? I guess i am doing mistake in using Logwrapper dll